# Sort loop by custom field from different post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, loop, meta-query

I have two different post types. Trainings and dates.
The post type for trainings has some basic informations about the specific training. Like a description, images and so on.
The date ist for informations like the date (obviously), the trainer and location.
And I add the training itself to the date.

I now want to sort all trainings by the next dates.
As I understand, I need to loop through the dates first and after that I need to loop though the trainings based on the text dates.

I've found some examples with multiple meta_queries. But is it possible to loop though multiple post types?

Comment: It seems like instead of two custom post types you need a custom taxonomy + a custom post type. That would make the queries easier and faster.

Comment: yes, but it is necessary to have these post types. I couldn't do it with a custom taxonomy + a custom post type

Comment: If you need to sort and view in different ways, perhaps what you're looking for is having "date" as a taxonomy, then a post type of "training" and one for "event." Event would be what you're currently calling a date, so that "date" could actually be a numeric date assigned to both CPTs. From there, on the "training" archive you set the main query to order by the "date" taxonomy, and on the "events" archive you can do the same and then display all "training" CPTs within a single date if you like.

Comment: OK, but I've already a custom field with date input (with ACF). Isn't it possible to sort by that field?

Comment: Yes, but sorting by a custom field is a slow operation that puts a lot of load on your database. Taxonomy will keep your site running faster.

Comment: Understood. But unfortunately it's not an option here :(

Comment: If both CPTs use the same fieldsets, you can do a WP_Query that pulls both CPTs and do loops from there. If they use different fieldsets, you'll have one query that pulls Dates, then foreach Date you'll have a separate query that pulls the Trainings associated with that Date.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. The CPTs don't share the same custom fields. I will have to look for an other solution :-(